# Android - Retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android application where older kids can pick up younger kids and walk to school. With the application the authenticated (email and password) younger kid can choose between three adresses to get picked up. As of right now my realtime database looks like this:

[image]

I want to retrieve the different addresses and the users who picked the addresses. I am thinking I have to use recyclerview to get the data, but I am unsure on if it is possible to do with my database structure.

[image]

Comment: That sounds feasible, but I'd definitely recommend looking at FirebaseUI to help with this. It has special adapters such as `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. For this specifically I'd look at: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I looked at the link you provided, but I am still in doubt on how to query the nodes. How do I get the username from the Adresses node?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I hope you don't mind me jumping in with an answer here - I had it drafted before spotting your comment!

Comment: @Grimthorr Perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734410/2754146), this one should accommodate your requirement to create a list of all addresses and their associated users, which may be closer to what you're looking for.

Again you can use the [FirebaseUI database package](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) to simplify the RecyclerView creation.

You'll need to start denormalizing your data, so your data structure should also include usernames in the addresses node:

```
{
  "Addresses" : {
    "Street 10" : {
      "name" : "Street 10",
      "users" : {
        "VAzdMWafK6cyhmJnOI4br5xiQg93" : "John"
      }
    }
  },
  "User" : {
    "VAzdMWafK6cyhmJnOI4br5xiQg93" : {
      "username" : "John",
      "address" : "Street 10"
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: you only need to add user IDs to their chosen address (and remove the node if they change selection), so don't use `"VAzdMWafK6cyhmJnOI4br5xiQg93" : false` for addresses the user has not selected as this could cause confusion.*

Then you can use:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Addresses");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Address> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Address>()
        .setQuery(query, Address.class)
        .build();
```

Where `Address` is something like:

```
public class Address {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> users;

    public Address() {}

    public Map<String, String> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And [create a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` instance](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter) from the `options` variable. Then when binding the viewholder in the adapter, you can access the `users` map to list each user that has selected this address, without the need to load the entire `User` object unnecessarily.

This pattern is called [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and is the suggested approach when using NoSQL databases (like Firebase Realtime Database). The main downside to this is data duplication: so for example, when a user changes their selected address, you'll need to change:

- The `address` value under the user, and
- the `users` list under the address.

Likewise, if a user is allowed to change their username, you'll need to update the username under their chosen address as well as in the user's node.

For details on dealing with this, see [this answer which explains a number of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30699277) (although the examples are in JavaScript, the premise still applies).

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this. I am sorry for the confusion from the original post

Comment: I have just finished creating the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter instance. I am in doubt on how to access the users map to list the users in my onBindViewHolder method. Any ideas?

Comment: So you should have access to the `model` parameter from `onBindViewHolder()` which will be an instance of the `Address` model for each row. You can then use `getUsers()` and [iterate over this map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066607). For example: `for (String username : model.getUsers.values()) { textView.append(username + " & ") }`.

Comment: Yes, I did this: https://pastebin.com/TE2ta8tL. But I am getting a database error "DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Boolean to String".

Comment: Check your database data to ensure there are no boolean values remaining under any of the `/Addresses/$address/users` nodes (see my example structure above).

Comment: Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: That's OK, no problem, I'm glad I could help. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [FirebaseUI database package](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) makes it simple to bind data from the Firebase Realtime Database to your app's UI. Specifically [using FirebaseUI with indexed data](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data) is applicable for your current database structure.

For example, you'd use something similar to:

```
// keyQuery - the Firebase location containing the list of keys to be found in dataRef
// dataRef - the Firebase location to watch for data changes. Each key found at 
//           keyRef's location represents a list item.

Query keyQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Addresses/Street 10/users");
DatabaseReference dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/User");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setIndexedQuery(keyQuery, dataRef, User.class)
        .build();
```

Where your User class is:

```
public class User {
    private String username;

    public User() {}

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can then use the above created `options` variable to [create a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` instance](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter) and then call [`startListening()`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle) on it*.

Using FirebaseUI in this way will automatically handle matching the keys under `/Addresses/Street 10/users` to the `/User` node.

---

<sub>* Version 2.x of FirebaseUI uses `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` instead and starts listening automatically so doesn't require a `startListening()` call. The above example is applicable for version 3.0, see [FirebaseUI 3.0 upgrade guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-3.0.md).</sub>

Comment: Can I ask how the constructor can be public Item?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I'll try it out

Comment: I tried it, but i am getting a weird error on FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter which says "cannot resolve symbol". I have used pastebin to paste my code. https://pastebin.com/cJJqJwaW

Comment: Hmm it seems like version 3.0 of FirebaseUI has done away with the dedicated `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` but hasn't updated their documentation! See the "indexed adapters" note in the [FirebaseUI 3.0 upgrade guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-3.0.md). Therefore in this version you can use the the standard `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` along with the `setIndexedQuery()` option for the same features.

Comment: I tried this: https://pastebin.com/Y5hejduc, but I am not getting anything on screen.

Comment: I checked the adapter and it is null. I don't get why it is empty

Comment: This is another [change made in version 3.0 of FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-3.0.md) (see "Adapter Lifecycle" note) - you need to explicity [call startListening() on the adapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle). Sorry, I've not used version 3.0 as it was only released recently. I've updated my answer with these changes.

Comment: This kind of work, but the problem here is that each user has its own row. So instead of all users assigned to the street being showed on the same index, each user has its own

Comment: That's correct. To list all addresses you can use a simple `setQuery()` option for the `/Addresses` node instead. From there, when the user selects one of these addresses, you can use the above adapter to list the users that have chosen this address (in a separate fragment for instance). I think this approach is preferable, because showing a list of all addresses with associated users in the same adapter would be costly to data and screen space. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Okay, I am a bit confused. What I originally wanted to display per row was: The name of the address and every username that has picked that address

Comment: Ah I see. This answer is for listing the users for one specific address using the indexed query. To do what you need, you'll need to start denormalizing & duplicating your data. I'll add another answer for this instead of changing this one again.